# Mod messages dropdown does too much HTML escaping for new meta questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, html-entities

The mod messages dropdown improperly HTML entity escapes the meta question introduction. I looked for similar bug reports on MSE but couldn't find any.

Because a screenshot is worth a hundred rep points (yay for mouse-drawn freehand ellipses!):

[image]

[This is the meta question in question.](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/450/29) It starts out with (note the link, which in the Markdown source is a plain URL to the question page, not a Markdown `[]()` link):

> So the bullet question.  [What can be used to make the world's deadliest bullet?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3184/what-can-be-used-to-make-the-worlds-deadliest-bullet)
>
> Something about this question (...)

The real Markdown source for the initial portion of the question is:

```
So the bullet question.  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3184/what-can-be-used-to-make-the-worlds-deadliest-bullet

Something about this question (...)
```

Comment: Taking a look at this. I see that it's encoded as `&amp;#39;`

Comment: @Haney Indeed; confirmed that encoding. Looking forward to a fix! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. I have corrected the encoding so that the summary of an entry on the mod menu is no longer double encoded. This is now live.

Here's what your mod menu now looks like:

[image: Your fixed mod menu]